# Migrate Global term store to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, term-store

How to migrate global term store of SharePoint 2013 into SharePoint Online. Please specify powershell commands if any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the term store and then import it to your new SharePoint online site.

For Powershell commands refer the below article

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1099878/Migrate-SharePoint-Taxonomy-Term-Stores-from-Share